# 'sh: 0: Can't open HoNClient-3.4.3.sh' when I try to run the HoNClient

Tags: software-installation, dash

I've been trying to install HoN on my laptop. It's running 32-bit Linux Mint 15. The problem I've run into is this: When I try to run the client in the terminal, using the command:

```
sudo sh HoNClient-3.4.3.sh
```

it gives me this:

```
sh: 0: Can't open HoNClient-3.4.3.sh
```

I've gone through and made the file executable, but it still doesn't work. Same thing happens when I try:

```
./HoNClient-3.4.3.sh
```

I'm just not sure what's going on, as I've never had this problem before. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and give us a link to wherever you downloaded the HoNClient-3.4.3.sh from. We can't really help unless we know exactly what you are dealing with.

Answer (score 1):

1. Change `HonClient-3.4.3.sh` to `HoNClient-3.4.3.zip`.
2. Extract to `HoNClient-3.4.3`
3. Open in a terminal: `/HoNClient-3.4.3/data/hon.sh`